# Inheritance between packages does not exist?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, package

Pardon me for a stupid question but It recently dawned on me that I've been doing things like this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
                  ^
                  |
```

for quite some time and I've been thinking "is this really necessary?"

The code below won't compile. My question is why?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ItemListener, ActionListener {
    ...
```

More specifically, since I'm importing `java.awt.*;`, shouldn't I be able to implement the listeners without doing `import java.awt.event.*;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Inheritance between packages does not exist?

Correct. A package is **just** a namespace, which (in Java, at least) are not nested.

> More specifically, since I'm importing `java.awt.*;`, shouldn't I be able to implement the listeners without doing import `java.awt.event.*;`?

The compile error you see clearly refutes this. Importing a package does not import its subpackages.